# Was there any evidence that Q civilization did NOT go through a "Savage" phase?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q

During "Encounter at Farpoint" ST:TNG episode, Q puts the human race - exemplified by USS Enterprise - on trial for savagery.

> You will now answer to the charge of being a grievously savage race!

**Is there any proof in canon that Q - as a race - did not have an equally savage past at the beginning of their development? Or vice versa, that they did?**

Please note that I'm referring to Q past - NOT to sometimes-deplorable behavior of TNG-era Q individuals.

Comment: Not answering, since it's not the past, but it was clearly still "in their blood" by the time of Voyager... as they had that whole civil war thing.

Comment: Didn't Q himself say once that they had evolved to those omnipotent beings?

Comment: @Bobby - they could have evolved from Ferengi(-like species) who were priding themselves on NOT having savage past

Comment: As soon as the Q became capable of time travel, their ancestors would have always been peaceful - or whatever else the modern Q want them to be :)

Comment: The trial happened because the Q were concerned that humans' savage past was too recent, for the amount of influence they have over that part of the galaxy.  Not because humans once were savage.

Comment: @Izkata - Correct. I didn't mean to imply that Q were savage right before TNG events.

Comment: What about the Q Civil War?  That surely counts as a savage phase, doesn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For convenience, I'm going to use "Q1" to refer to the Q played by John DeLancie.

There is, in canon, no direct answer for this.  There's some evidence that points in two different directions.

There's mixed evidence in canon for this (and against it).  In the *Star Trek: Voyager* episode [*Death Wish*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Death_Wish_%28episode%29), Quinn, the Q who wants to die and later takes the name Quinn states that the Q were once like humanoid life forms.  However, he never mentions any history of savagery.  Since Quinn is disenchanted with the Q, it could mean that either he has a twisted view of them or a more realistic view of them then the rest of the Q.

In [*The Q And the Grey*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Q_and_the_Grey_%28episode%29) Q1 says or implies strongly that the Q were never created, but always have been as they are.

While this is not authoritative and Q1 is quite irascible, he seems to stick to the truth and, where possible, tell a truth that will be frustrating to the humans in the situation.  He doesn't tend to lie and doesn't seem to need to.

In terms of canon, these are the only references we get to the history of the Q. (I had hoped for more from *Death Wish*, but there really wasn't much there in terms of Q history.)

Later, in [*Q2*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Q2_%28episode%29) Q1's son, referred to in the title as Q2, writes an essay on the history of the Q, but we never find out what's in it.  (But the fact that there is a history implies that they've done more than just exist in the continuum for all eternity.)

Other than these examples, there's nothing in canon about the past of the Q, and with this scanty information, it's more likely Q1 is right than Quinn, who had is own view of the Q and the continuum.

Comment: +1 for use of the word 'irascible', a word I have never before seen or heard until today.